# How to request.form from a jinja2 loop in an html template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

so i have a feed on my website listing all the new "proposals" made recently.
These are listed in a jinja2 loop in my html template. The thing is, that i have rating buttons under each proposal, and i want to be able to get the rating the user clicked on in python and then send it to the database.
But i don't really know how to do that as i'm still a beginner..

So here is what i have in my html template :

```
            {% for proposition in propositions %}
            <div class="feed_propBox"> <!--prop Box: Begin-->
                <form method="POST" action="rate">

                    <p  id="titre" name="titre" value="{{proposition.title}}">{{ proposition.title }}</p>
                    <p  id="perso" name="perso">{{ proposition.date }}</p>
                    <p  id="content" name="content">{{ proposition.content }}</p>

                    <div class="ratingBlock">
                        <button type="submit" class="mThree ratingButton" id="m3" name="rate" value="m3">-3</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="mTwo ratingButton" id="m2" name="rate" value="m2">-2</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="mOne ratingButton" id="m1" name="rate" value="m1">-1</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="zero ratingButton" id="z" name="rate" value="z">0</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="pOne ratingButton" id="p1" name="rate" value="p1">1</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="pTwo ratingButton" id="p2" name="rate" value="p2">2</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="pThree ratingButton" id="p3" name="rate" value="p3">3</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div> <!--prop Box: End-->
            {% endfor %}
```

In my python views.py, i have this for my feed :

```
@bp.route('/rate', methods=['POST','GET'])
def rate():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        note_list = ["m3", "m2", "m1", "z", "p1", "p2", "p3"]
        for i in note_list:
            titre = request.form["titre"]
            note = request.form['rate']
            if note == i:
                note = note_list.index(i)
                client.POSTS.rating.insert_one({"title" : titre, "rate" : note})
    return redirect(url_for('.proposer'))
```

But well, i get this error when clicking on a rating button :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/gabriel/Dropbox/Evrisops/Evrisops_Server/views/routes.py", line 252, in rate
    titre = request.form["titre"]
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 431, in __getitem__
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'titre'
```

Anyways, i think the problem may only come from "title" but i have no idea how to fix that either...

BTW, do you guys know how to append a value to an array in a json document ? Using python and mongodb operator :/

Thanks alot :)

Comment: before going deeper... maybe just a misspelling error (tit**r**e insted of tit**l**e)? ```titre = request.form["title"]```

Comment: No, that's just because it's french... There seems to be no misspelling error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the way to do that some time ago
If it can help anyone :
just use `request.form.get('')` instead of `request.form['']`
Along with an input with hidden property to get the value of the proposition.title.
:)

Answer (score 1):

I think the error comes from this line :

```
titre = request.form["titre"]
```

You probably don't have a `titre` key in the `request.form` object.
To debug this, I suggest to add a `print request.form` in the loop so you can see the structure of the object.

Moreover, if `request.form["titre"]` is empty, it is probably because you are setting a `value` attribute on a `<p>` element which is not allowed in HTML.

According tho [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp) the `value` attribute can't be set on a `<p>` element. Try to switch to an `<input>` element.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the thing is that i don't want it to be something else than a text. The thing is that i just want to get the ```{{ proposition.title }}```that was sent by python to the html template with jinja2 back to python again for data storage...                 I changed `<p>` to `<option>` which is supposed to support the `value` attribute, but still same error.

Comment: Hi, when i `print request.form` i get this : `ImmutableMultiDict([('rate', 'p1')])`

Comment: Hi so i changed `request.form` to `request.form.get`. I don't get the error in the browser no more but i still get `ImmutableMultiDict([('rate', 'p1')])` in the terminal... And now i get that `title = null` in my json document sent to the database.

Comment: An `<option>` tag goes into a `<select>` tag. The value is not sent when you post your form. You are not using your HTML tags correctly inside your form. Try with another tag. If you want to pass data without displaying anything to the user you can use a `hidden` property : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp

Comment: Hi, i am using `hidden` property inside `<input>` as you said, still get the same `ImmutableMultiDict` error...